# How to enable scrolling if text is disable for android

Tags: android, scroll, disable

How to enable scrolling if text is `editable={false}` (disable) for Android, but for iOS have property `multiline={true}` and the scroll works for iOS, but I need to do it for Android, maybe you know?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this line of code

```
EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.etext);
 editText.setKeyListener( null );
 //editText.setFocusable( false );
 editText.setCursorVisible(false);
```